# quiver plot with 3-dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, plot

At my problem I have a potential which dependent of all three dimensions. The problem is highly symmetric. To approximate the the dependence I am only interested in a mesh of points:

```
 V=np.zeros((npoints,npoints,npoints))
x=0
while x<10:
    for i in range(1,npoints-2):
        for j in range(1,npoints-2):
            for k in range(1,npoints-2):
                V[i,j,k]=1.0/6.0*(V[i+1,j,k]+V[i-1,j,k]+V[i,j+1,k]+V[i,j-1,k]+V[i,j,k+1]+V[i,j,k-1]+rho[i,j,k]*dx**2)
    x=x+1
```

The code is not so interesting, but should give you a basic idea how I setup the problem.
Analog I create three values Ex[i,j,k], Ey[i,j,k] and Ez[i,j,k] for my problem.

Now the task is to create a quiver plot of that problem and I was referring to that source:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html

My quiver plot shall only be two-dimensional so that I can set:

```
x=np.linspace(-2,2,9)
y=np.linspace(-2,2,9)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
U=np.zeros((npoints, npoints))
for i in range(0,npoints):
    for j in range(0,npoints):
        U = Ex[i,j,4]
for i in range(0,npoints):
    for j in range(0,npoints):
        V = Ey[i,j,4]
```

So know I have a mesh of points and a two dimensinal set of Vectors for my problem, but I do not know how I shall continue.
Any suggestions? Do I do something wrong. That is my first quiverplot.